# Is there a subgroup $H \leq G$ such that $C_G(N) \cong H \times N $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal abelian subgroup of $G$. Suppose $G$ splits over $N$ with complement $K$ (that is, $G=NK$ and $N\cap K=1$). Is there a subgroup $H \leq G$ such that $C_G(N) \cong H \times N $?

Since $N$ is abelian, I know that $N\leq C_G(N)$ and also $N$ is normal in the centralizar. I have been trying to give a another subgroup $H$ that is normal in the centralizer and that has trivial intersection with $N$ in order to prove that the centralizer equals the direct internal product of those two groups, but I have not been successful.

Any hints as to how to approach this problem would be really helpful.

Comment: I think that $H=C_G(N)\cap K$.

Comment: More generally: If $K$ is a complement of $N$ in $G$ and $N\le H\le G$, then $H\cap K$ is a complement of $N$ in $H$.